# Can I make Java go faster?

Tags: java, networking

I was making a file-transfer program and it takes forever to transmit this 800kb test picture I made. Clearly I don't want to spend 30 minutes for every mb of data, so I was curious if there was any way to speed up my code or Java in general. I had heard about allocating extra RAM, but never looked into it.

If anyone can find a better algorithm for my code that would be appreciated, otherwise I may have to step to C++ or C and try again.

Server code block:

```
if(file.exists()){
    for(long l=0;l<file.length();l++){
        out.writeByte(fIS.read());
    }                   
}
```

where fIS is the FileInputStream and out is the outgoing DataOutputStream. The rest of the code is basically sending lengths and a flag, but I can add if requested.

Client Code:

```
b = new byte[len];
for(int x=0;x<len;x++){
    b[x] = dIS.readByte();
}
fOS.write(b);
```

where len is the read length of the file expected from the Server, b is the array of bytes that make up the file, dIS is the input stream from the server, and fOS is the FileOutputStream.

I also just attempted using Readers and readLine() with writeChars() and readChar(), but this seems to equate to about the same thing.

Comment: Try write a byte array instead of individual bytes. Also look over network packet/traffic sizes for some idea of the size of buffer you should try using. Take a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: "So I know Java is a slow language" [citation needed]

Comment: (i) Java is not slow, (ii) your program is I/O bound, so the language is mostly irrelevant - what matters is how you use the I/O libraries.

Comment: If your Java code is significantly slower than identical C++ code, you are definitely doing something wrong. Java is not slow, your code is.

Comment: Someone dare to say that Java is slow. :O

Comment: Which is exactly what I was asking if you would read. If my code was slow, give me a better algorithm. I don't mind being told I'm wrong so long as you offer something better.

Comment: It isn't 'exactly what you were asking', it is a contradiction of what you actually said. If you don't want the downvotes, don't introduce dubious and irrelevant matter into your questions.

Comment: "If anyone can find a better algorithm for my code that would be appreciated" Yeah. It was. Either better algorithm or tell me that java can't be sped up. I think I know my question thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Reading a file a byte at a time and sending over the network one byte at a time is going to be slow in any language :)

Consider using a [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) for reading and [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) for writing.

Comment: +1 for being constructive instead of "JAVA AINT SLOW AND YOU SHOULD FEEL BAD".

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot. I'd also +1 but because I get downvoted for "beginner" questions I don't have the rep >.>